# Solve $\frac{(x-1)^{204}(x+3)^5(x-4)^{2015}}{(x+5)^{102}}\ge 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Solve $\frac{(x-1)^{204}(x+3)^5(x-4)^{2015}}{(x+5)^{102}}\ge 0$ Just wanted to share a nice and quick technique i learnt for such problems.

Comment: The function in the LHS is continuous over $(-\infty,-5)$ and over $(-5,+\infty)$ and it may change its sign only by going through $x\in\{-5,-3,1,4\}$, so we just have five intervals to check.

Comment: I did that,see my answer below.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately plot the critical points -5__-3____1__4 on a number line.Check for validity of each range by taking a number in that range.For x<-5 take -6;it holds true.For (-5,-3);-4 satisfies the inequality so x this range holds true.For (-3,1) take 0;the inequality does not hold.For (1,4) take 2 and check;it again does not hold.For x>4 take 5 to check;it holds.Now check the critical points ${-5,-3,1,4}$.Out of these ${-3,1,4}$ hold.So the solution of x is: $x<-5,-5<x<=-3,x>=4,x=1$

Answer (score 1):

For the equality, $x=1,-3,4$

For $\dfrac{(x-1)^{204}(x+3)^5(x-4)^{2015}}{(x+5)^{102}}>0,$

As $x$ is real, the problem reduces to $(x+3)(x-4)>0\iff x>4$ or $x<-3$

But the denominator is undefined  at $x+5=0$

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, Why that is required at all as for the terms in the numerator $(x-a)^2\ge0$ for real $x-a$

Comment: Yes you are right. :-)

Comment: @Macavity, Please find the edited version

Answer (score 1):

By the rule of signs, factors with  an even exponent are $\geq 0$ and those with an odd exponent have the same sign as with exponent $1$. Hence, if $x\neq -5\,$:
\begin{align*}
 \frac{(x-1)^{204}(x+3)^5(x-4)^{2015}}{(x+5)^{102}}\geq 0&\iff (x+3)(x-4)\geq 0\enspace\text{or}\enspace x=1\\
&\iff x\leq -3\enspace\text{or}\enspace x=1\enspace\text{or}\enspace x\geq 4
\end{align*}
Thus the set $\mathcal S$ of solutions is:
$$\mathcal S=(-\infty,-5)\cup(-5,-3]\cup\{1\}\cup[4,+\infty).$$

Comment: Yes but just add x=1.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot it! Answer completed. Thank you for pointing it.